# Freebsd iscsi initiator

Tags: freebsd

Freebsd 8.0-RELEASE

Знатоки Freebsd, подскажите, как подключить блочный диск по iscsi.

Есть NAS, на котором создан iscsi раздел, без авторизации и iqn.

На клиенте(Freebsd) есть утилита iscontrol

**/etc/iscsi.conf**

```
idisk1 {
TargetName=iqn.2018-09.tgt1:backup
TargetAddress=10.10.51.14:3260,1
}
```

Делаю подключение:

```
#iscontrol -c /etc/iscsi.conf -n idisk1
iscontrol[22634]: running
```

в /dev появляется файлик iscsi
но самого блочного устройства не вижу.

С Windows и Linux клиента, этот таргет подключается без проблем.

Comment: `gpart show` показывает его?

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov, нет.
    `gpart show`
и
    `geom disk list`
показываю только локальные диски. А процесс `root           22634  0.0  0.1  3444  1020  ??  Is    4:30PM   0:00.00 iscontrol -c /etc/iscsi.conf -n idisk1`, как бы работает